# How to run selenium scripts written in java from jmeter?

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

I am trying to use my Selenium scripts in java with JMeter's WebDriver  Sampler.

Inside the webdriver sampler, the language is seleced to java, and the following code added:

```
package automationFramework;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Launch the Online Store Website
        driver.get("www.google.com");

        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.google.com");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(5);

        // Close the driver
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I am facing the following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:80)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, tests written in javascripts work just fine.

What is the problem here? How to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You should not be instantiating WebDriver instance, JMeter does it for you given you add [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) element to your Test Plan and configure path to the ChromeDriver executable.

Once done you should be able to use `WDS.browser` shorthand like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("http://google.com");
WDS.log.info("Successfully opened the website www.google.com");
Thread.sleep(5000);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

[image: JMeter WebDriver Sampler Demo]

Also don't call `quit()` method, the WebDriver instance(s) will be shut down when test will be finished.

See [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) guide to get started with Selenium and JMeter integration.

Comment: Can't I define classes in a proper java syntax, that is, can I just copy paste my selenium scripts here so that it should work as expected, or the scripts needs to be changed according to the format of jmeter?

Comment: Using WebDriver Sampler you cannot. You may look into [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler where you have full freedom and if your tests are JUnit-based it might be the case you won't even need to change them. See How to [Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article to get started.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome driver 2.28 with Selenium 3.x.x you have to set the path of the Chrome driver before you open the browser.

Add this line:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_folder\\chrome.exe");`

Next, `WebDriver driver;`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The browser appears, blinks and goes stopped (Just like before).  I think this is some configuration related issue in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this is extract you webdriver test in a jar file then run in using a junit test in JMeter.